# Is there any formalization of GADTs implemented in OCaml?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, data-types, ocaml

There are papers that describe how generalized algebraic datatypes (GADTs) are encoded in core Haskell (System FC)[1][2], but I could not find any documentation on how OCaml formalizes/implements/encodes GADTs and how does it compare to Haskell GADTs.

**Question**: How are GADTs formalized/implemented/encoded in the core language of OCaml and how do they compare to Haskell?

To be more precise: I want to understand GADTs as implemented from a compiler writer/theoretician point of view and *not* from a point of view of a programmer as described here [3][4].

1. [OUTSIDEIN(X) Modular type inference with local assumptions](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0956796811000098)
2. [System F with type equality coercions](https://doi.org/10.1145/1190315.1190324)
3. [OCaml Manual GADT tutorial](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/gadts-tutorial.html)
4. [Real world OCaml GADT](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/gadts.html)

Comment: You would've seen [Chapter 7 of the _OCaml Manual_](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/gadts-tutorial.html) and [Chapter 6 of _Real World OCaml_](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/gadts.html)?

Comment: Both of those sections show how and (possibly when) to _use_ GADTs from a programmers point of view. I'm searching for formalization of GADTs from a compiler implementor/theoreticians point of view.

Comment: Perhaps you can [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking, so that others don't have the same misconception, and give background on related material that you are familiar with, which isn't what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first work that talks about formalizing seems to be:

1. Xi, Hongwei, Chiyan Chen, and Gang Chen. “Guarded Recursive Datatype Constructors.” In Proceedings of the 30th ACM SIGPLAN-SIGACT Symposium on Principles of Programming Languages, 224–35. POPL ’03. New York, NY, USA: Association for Computing Machinery, 2003. https://doi.org/10.1145/604131.604150.

The implementation aspects seems to be based on this presentation from OCaml workshop

2. Jacques Garrigue, Jacques Le Normand. "Adding GADTs to OCaml: the direct approach." ACM SIGPLAN Workshop on ML 2011. [https://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~garrigue/papers/ml2011.pdf](https://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/%7Egarrigue/papers/ml2011.pdf)

Also some work on mechanized formalization of GADTs

3. Jacques Garrigue, Xuanrui Qi. "Formalizing OCaml GADT typing in Coq." The ML 2021. [https://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~garrigue/cocti/ml2021.pdf](https://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/%7Egarrigue/cocti/ml2021.pdf)